# Hide views in Eclipse RCP - customize perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, rcp, perspective

In my IDE based Eclipse application there is some views, I don't need, for example Outline view, or Tasks. So far I have found some solutions, to do that using activities or perspectives, but the problem is, it works with menu commands. I want to prepare my custom perspective at the launch of IDE. Which class or interface should I implement to intercept the behavior of Eclipse on startup?

Comment: The Activities extension point should be active at startup - is that what you are using?

Comment: Yes, I try to use Activity. I understand, I have to bind desired UI elements via 
activityPatternBinding, and then enable my Activity?

Comment: Activities defined using the org.eclipse.ui.activities extension point are automatically enabled by default.

Comment: Ok, currently, I can control views from IWorkbenchActivitySupport. But how to call it on the launch?

Comment: Why are you do you need to do that? What is wrong with using the extension point what will work automatically?

Comment: I decided to solve my problem using org.eclipse.ui.perspctives extension point., and it works for me. Thanks for replies :)